# Can I have a grid as background on a Vis.js Network

Tags: javascript, angular, vis.js, vis.js-network

I'm implementing a network chart using Vis.js, and I'd like to have a grid as background
Do you have any idea how can I achieve that and if I can achieve that?

Comment: Use the `background` property in CSS?

Comment: Will it zoom in and out when I do it with the network?

Comment: No, it would be static.

Comment: So it won't be useful, I need a greed that is in "sync" with the network, move it and zoom it in the same way I do with the network

Answer (score 1):

Example using [`beforeDrawing`](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/docs/network/#Events) (per this [example](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/examples/network/data/scalingNodesEdges.html)):

```js
// create an array with nodes
var nodes = new vis.DataSet([
  { id: 1, value: 2, label: "Algie" },
  { id: 2, value: 31, label: "Alston" },
  { id: 3, value: 12, label: "Barney" },
  { id: 4, value: 16, label: "Coley" },
  { id: 5, value: 17, label: "Grant" },
  { id: 6, value: 15, label: "Langdon" },
  { id: 7, value: 6, label: "Lee" },
  { id: 8, value: 5, label: "Merlin" },
  { id: 9, value: 30, label: "Mick" },
  { id: 10, value: 18, label: "Tod" },
]);

// create an array with edges
var edges = new vis.DataSet([
  { from: 2, to: 8, value: 3, title: "3 emails per week" },
  { from: 2, to: 9, value: 5, title: "5 emails per week" },
  { from: 2, to: 10, value: 1, title: "1 emails per week" },
  { from: 4, to: 6, value: 8, title: "8 emails per week" },
  { from: 5, to: 7, value: 2, title: "2 emails per week" },
  { from: 4, to: 5, value: 1, title: "1 emails per week" },
  { from: 9, to: 10, value: 2, title: "2 emails per week" },
  { from: 2, to: 3, value: 6, title: "6 emails per week" },
  { from: 3, to: 9, value: 4, title: "4 emails per week" },
  { from: 5, to: 3, value: 1, title: "1 emails per week" },
  { from: 2, to: 7, value: 4, title: "4 emails per week" },
]);

// create a network
var container = document.getElementById("mynetwork");
var data = {
  nodes: nodes,
  edges: edges,
};
var options = {
  nodes: {
    shape: "dot",
  },
};
var network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);

network.on("beforeDrawing", function(ctx) {

  var width = ctx.canvas.clientWidth;
  var height = ctx.canvas.clientHeight;
  var spacing = 40;
  var gridExtentFactor = 4;
  ctx.strokeStyle = "lightgrey";
  
  // draw grid
  ctx.beginPath();
  for (var x = -width * gridExtentFactor; x <= width * gridExtentFactor; x += spacing) {
    ctx.moveTo(x, height * gridExtentFactor);
    ctx.lineTo(x, -height * gridExtentFactor);
  }
  for (var y = -height * gridExtentFactor; y <= height * gridExtentFactor; y += spacing) {
    ctx.moveTo(width * gridExtentFactor, y);
    ctx.lineTo(-width * gridExtentFactor, y);
  }
  ctx.stroke();
  
});
```

```css
#mynetwork {
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  background-color: none;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/vis-network/standalone/umd/vis-network.min.js"></script>
<div id="mynetwork"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[vis-network](https://github.com/visjs/vis-network) uses a html5 canvas to draw the chart. You could draw the grid yourself using the `beforeDrawing` event. To support interactivity like zooming and panning you would also need to listen to the `dragStart`, `dragging` and `dragEnd` events as well as `zoom`. With these events it should be possible to implement a fully interactive background.

Have a look at the [renderEvents example](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/examples/network/events/renderEvents.html) and the [interactionEvents example](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/examples/network/events/interactionEvents.html).

Comment: I'm using D3.js for plotting a grid, and Vis.js for the Network, now I have to make them work together

Comment: @mojoaxel - see my answer below using `beforeDrawing` - pan and zoom seems to come out of the box (which is awesome, don't get me wrong). Why would we handle the drag events as well ?